# Meteor: sortablejs method not being called

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor

I've got a component that when simplified looks like so:

```
import Sortable from 'react-sortablejs';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  updateItemOrder() {
    let items = this.props.items;
    items.forEach((item, index) => {
      console.log(item._id);
      console.log(index);

      updateItem.call({ _id: item._id, update: { priority: index } });
    });
  };

  render() {
    <Sortable
      tag='ul'
      className='item-list list-group'
      onChange={ this.updateItemOrder() }>
        { this.renderItems() }
    </Sortable>
  }
}
```

My console lists the `item._id` and the `index` on page load, but nothing happens when I drag-and-drop items in my sortable list. Changing to a `<ReactSortable>` component doesn't help, either (as per the [docs](https://github.com/cheton/react-sortable)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your above code specifically this part here,

```
updateItemOrder() {
    let items = this.props.items;
    items.forEach((item, index) => {
      console.log(item._id);
      console.log(index);

      updateItem.call({ _id: item._id, update: { priority: index } });
    });
  };
```

It would seem that you are trying to mutate props which is a no go in react. To cause a re-render in react, you need to update state and tell react this change is state should cause a re-render. This is done using `setState`. There 2 options that come to mind right of the bat. First you can capture your props in the local state of this component and update that, or you can call a method back in your parent component to update its state forcing it to re-render.